# how do a button scroll vertical with javascript?

Tags: javascript, scroll

I need a `javascript` for a button.

I need a vertical scroll anchored to the next div every time i click the button.

It's something like a carousel but with one button.

Every time I click the button the number inside decreases (from 3 to 2 to one)

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/fortunatofatiga/5fop2ht1/)
the fiddle

Comment: You saw a red warning before tried to post your question, right? What did the warning say?

Comment: What is your question? I couldn't see any javascript on your fiddle.

Comment: you don't see any js because i havent put it

Answer (score 0):

hi try add this JAVASCIRPT

like this https://jsfiddle.net/qhurjd83/

```
document.getElementById("next").addEventListener("click",next);


function next(){
var docpage = document.getElementById("page");
var page = parseInt(docpage.innerText) == 3? 1  : parseInt(docpage.innerText)+1;
docpage.innerText = page;

document.getElementById(page==1 ? "one":page==2?"two":"three").scrollIntoView();
}
```

Comment: Good it works! But there's a little bug because when i click the button the page (jsfiddle) seems cropped on the top. I just need that the button works on the code